# Finding the non-unique inverse dot-product

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an equation $\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y} = K$ over $\mathbb{R}^n$.  I want to solve for $\vec{y}$ in terms of parameters.  I tried taking the pseudo-inverse of $\vec{x}$, but I end up with a larger square matrix multiplying $\vec{y}$, which doesn't seem solve-able.  Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Find one solution $\vec y_p$.  Then find the orthogonal complement of $\vec x$.  Call it $W^\bot$.  Then $\vec y_p + W^\bot$ should solve your equation.

Comment: Is the orthogonal compliment the same as the null space of $\vec{x}$?

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky Yes. For a fixed $\vec x$, you have a linear equation of a hyperplane that you can solve in various well-known ways, including the one in Bye_World’s comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By inverting the dot product $\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{y} = K$ for $\mathbf{y}$, I suppose you want to find all solutions $\mathbf{y}$ such that $\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{y} = K$ holds.

To do so, note that every vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be written as $c\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{x}^\perp$, where $c$ is some scalar, and where $\mathbf{x}^\perp$ is a vector orthogonal to $\mathbf{x}$. The dot product is completely blind to $\mathbf{x}^\perp$ since $\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{x}^\perp=0$ by definition, so the most general solution for $\mathbf{y}$ would be given by
$$\mathbf{y} = \frac{K}{\|\mathbf{x}\|^2}\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{x}^\perp,$$
for any arbitrary vector $\mathbf{x}^\perp$ orthogonal to $\mathbf{x}$.

Note that the pseudoinverse to $\mathbf{x}^\mathrm{T}$ is given by 
$\mathbf{x}/\|\mathbf{x}\|^2$, so taking $K$ times the psuedo-inverse would've given you a valid solution also, the minimum norm solution in fact, but not the most general solution.